# Creating an adjacency matrix and its notation?

Tags: graph-theory, notation, adjacency-matrix

Lets say I divide an image up into small squares (100 in total). I pick say 20 squares at random, and each is denoted by, $\text{Z}$. So the first square is $\text{Z}_{\text{1}}$, the second is $\text{Z}_{\text{2}}$ and so fourth. I want to see if their boundaries $\mathcal{B}$ intersect, i.e. if the squares happen to be directly next to each other on the image.

I created an adjacency matrix:

\begin{equation}
A_{\text{i,j}}=\left\{
\begin{alignedat}{3}
1,&\quad \text{if} \quad \text{i}\neq\text{j}\enspace\text{and}\enspace\exists\mathcal{B}:  \mathcal{B}\in\text{Z}_{\text{i}}\cap\text{Z}_{\text{j}}\\
0,&\quad \text{if} \quad \text{i}=\text{j} \\
0,&\quad \text{otherwise}
\end{alignedat}\,
\right\}
\end{equation}

1) How do I remove the right curly bracket?

2) Does the condition, $\exists\mathcal{B}: \mathcal{B}\in\text{Z}_{\text{i}}\cap\text{Z}_{\text{j}}$, make sense or is there a better way to write it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) To remove the curly bracket you can use `\right.` instead of `\right\}`.

2) The conditions makes sense.  You could write $Z_i \cap Z_j \neq \emptyset$ to be slightly more succinct.  Or even just use words to be more plain:

> Set $A_{i,j} = 1$ if $Z_i$ and $Z_j$ are adjacent (and not equal), otherwise $0$.

Comment: Does the $\neq 0$ mean the union of the set is not empty?

Comment: It means the intersection is not empty.

Comment: ok thanks. I have written the condition as $\exists\mathcal{B}: \text{Z}_{\text{i}}\cap\text{Z}_{\text{j}}\neq0$ and also explained in the text the meaning in words for completeness. Thanks for your swift reponse.

Comment: Well, the condition you have written in the comment looks strange.  If $\exists B B \in Z_i \cap Z_j$ then you know $Z_i \cap Z_j \neq \emptyset$.  The two statements are equivalent.  By the way, note the difference between $0$ (a number) and $\emptyset$ (a set).

Comment: Yes, I had just edited my comment upon looking back on it just before you replied. 

Thank you for bringing to my attention to the symbol, $\emptyset$. I think I will use the original condition from my OP, simply because its easier for me and my readers (from a physics/Eng background) to understand. Thanks once again.

Comment: Thinking about this, it may be confusing to say $Z_i \cap Z_j \neq \emptyset$ (or $\exists B\, B \in Z_i \cap Z_j$).  In the context of image processing, a square is probably thought of as a collection of pixels, not an ideal square from geometry.  So two adjacent squares would not have any pixels in common.  You could just say $A_{i,j} = 1$ if $Z_i$ and $Z_j$ touch (either on a side or a corner.)

Comment: Aside: A common mistake of authors writing math is to think that it's not formal unless it is written in mathematical notation.  For a simple definition the English language is often easier to understand.  With that I will leave it to you...

Comment: Hi, my application is not actually squares but shapes of arbitrary shapes. I will think of using english to write that condition instead. I do think you are right, its probably going to be clearest writing plain english

Answer (score 0):

I didnt understood your first question so i will directly answer the second one. The condition makes sense as long as you can compute the adjency matrix A and it should ne written as : 
Given x a vector where x_i=1 if the square i is chosen, 0 otherwise. Hence x contains 20 composants equal to 1 and 80 equal to zero. You compute the product Ax  ans see it the resulting vector is null. If it is the case, there is no intersection, if not there must be some squares with common boundery.